# How do I parse this Craigslist page in this particular way?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

This is the page in question: http://phoenix.craigslist.org/cpg/

What I would like to do is to create an array that looks like this:

Date (as captured by the h4 tag on that page) =>  in cell `[0][0][0]`,
Link Text => in cell `[0][1][0]`
Link href => in cell `[0][1][1]`

i.e. in each row, I store each of those items per row.

What I have done is simply pulled all the `h4` tags in and stored them in a hash like this:

```
contents2[link[:date]] = content_page.css("h4").text
```

The problem with this is that one cell stores all the text from the h4 tags on the entire page...whereas I would like to have 1 date to 1 cell.

So as an example:

```
0 => Mon May 28 - Leads need follow up - (Phoenix) - http://phoenix.craigslist.org/wvl/cpg/3043296202.html
1=> Mon May 28 - .Net/Java Developers - (phoenix) - http://phoenix.craigslist.org/cph/cpg/3043067349.html
```

Any thoughts on how I might approach this, with code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How's this?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://phoenix.craigslist.org/cpg/"))

# Postings start inside the second blockquote on the page
bq = doc.xpath('//blockquote')[1]

date  = nil         # Temp store of date of postings
posts = Array.new   # Store array of all postings here

# Loop through all blockquote children collecting data as we go along...
bq.children.each { |nod|
  # The date is stored in the h4 nodes. Grab it from there.
  date = nod.text if nod.name == "h4"

  # Skip nodes until we have a date
  next if !date

  # Skip nodes that are not p blocks. The p blocks contain the postings.
  next if nod.name != "p"

  # We have a p block. Extract posting data.
  link = nod.css('a').first['href']
  text = nod.text

  # Add new posting to array
  posts << [date, text, link]
}

# Output everything we just collected
posts.each { |p| puts p.join(" - ") }
```

Comment: This is cool...never knew I could skip items as I am iterating with `each`. Nicely commented too. That's cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are other ways but traverse is probably the easiest once again:

```
doc.traverse do |node|
  @date = node.text if node.name == 'h4'
  next unless @date
  break if node.text['next 100 postings']
  puts [@date, node.parent.text, node[:href]].join(' - ') if node.name == 'a'
end
```

Comment: That's a nice compact solution. However it will catch some stray links from the page still...should be easy to fix though. Also `node.text` could be changed to `node.parent.text` to grab all the text from the posting.

Comment: One issue I have found with this solution so far is that it spazzes out on nil objects.